# Semicolon after double slash in C

Tags: c, comments

I have a question about comments in C language. 
When we write for example

```
//this is the first step
```

This means a comment.

But when we write

```
//this is the first step;
```

Does this also mean a comment? I mean when we add semicolon after double slash, does this mean a comment or main part of the program?

Comment: still a comment, anything on the same line after // will be a comment.

Comment: Whatever comes after the two slashes and before the linefeed is ignored by the compiler.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the question shows no research. You didn't even try it on your favourite compiler (which, while not an indicator of correctness, would constitute research).

Comment: I have asked the question because I don't have the compiler. I am trying to understand code to write it using another program.

Comment: It's probably just a programmers thing... for some time even when writing i.e. an e-mail I was habitually ending every line with a semicolon;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double slash comments out the line yes. The compiler will ignore the whole line (including semi-colons, yes).

For multi line comments, or commenting on the same line as some code, use /* comment here */

Wiki has some good information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Comments

Note (from Wiki):

> C++ style line comments start with // and extend to the end of the
>   line. This style of comment originated in BCPL and became valid C
>   syntax in C99; it is not available in the original K&R C nor in ANSI
>   C:

Answer (score 10):

**Everything after double slashes is a comment.**

This includes semicolons, operators, preprocessor directives, keywords and even cats.

EDIT:

Something I find interesting:

```
//comment \
also part of the comment\
this too part of the comment
```

I guess back-slashes are actually parsed. That is the line continuation character. Worth mentioning I think.

I guess the SO parser doesn't recognize the character, but it does exist - at least in MSVC. Not sure if it's part of the standard or not.

EDIT 2:

As @vsz pointed out, a trigraph will be parsed even if in a comment:

```
/*
??/ is translated to \   
the following is not safe:
*/

//do we really need this??/
i++;
```

The previous code `i++;` will not get executed, since `??/` is replaced by `\` and so `i++;` becomes part of the comment.

Comment: What are cats in that context?

Comment: A small domesticated carnivorous mammal with soft fur, a short snout, and retractile claws. It is widely kept as a pet or for catching mice, and many breeds have been developed.

Comment: This is why the following can be dangerous:  `//What will the following line do??/` because the `??/` will be replaced with a backslash because it is a trigraph.

Comment: The preprocessor is actually the thing that removes comments, during tokenization. Since the `\` character is also processed by the preprocessor before tokenization, this will work on lines with comments.

Comment: Yeah the preprocessor has the following phases (in order): trigraph replacement, line concatenation, tokenization (where comments are removed), macro expansion/evaluation

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon is just another character in the comment.

It stands to reason that the practice of placing a semicolon at the end of a comment line is someone **cheating on lines-of-code metrics**... rudimentary calculations count semicolons as a proxy for statements. They should be ashamed of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

No characters after a double-slash comment are parsed. It's stripped by the pre-processor. The compiler never sees it.

Comment: By the tokenizer I would say.

Answer (score 0):

`//`-style comments go to the end of the line. Semicolons are not treated specially; semicolons end *statements*, while comments are not statements.

Answer (score 0):

It remains a comment: neither this:

```
// Hello, world
```

nor this:

```
// Hello, world;
```

Will be executed

Answer (score 0):

The // delimits everything that follows it *on the same line*. Everything. That was you can be confident that whatever you choose to comment will remain a comment.

Contrast that with /* */ where confusion can arise. For example:

/* This is a /* bad comment */ */

// but this is a /* good comment */

Answer (score 0):

`//` line comments come in all kinds and shapes. Everything is ignored up to the end of the line. `\` at the end of the line makes the comment extend to the next line. Here is an extreme corner case:

```
\
/\
/|\
-+-\
\|/ \
 V   \
```